# UDP Server/Client for Game

Tags: java, networking, server, udp, client

I am trying to put together a tank game and I am having issues with the networking part. What am I doing wrong on the server??

Here is my server code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class UDPServer extends Thread{
    private DatagramSocket socket;
    private TanksComponent tank;
    private InetAddress IPAddress;
    private int port = 9876;

    public void UPDServer() throws IOException{
        socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
            try {
                socket.receive(packet);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + packet.getAddress() + " " + packet.getPort() + ": " + new String(packet.getData()) ) ;
            IPAddress = packet.getAddress();
        }
    }
    public void sendData(byte[] data){
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, IPAddress, port);
        try {
            this.socket.send(packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my client code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class UDPClient extends Thread{
    private InetAddress ipAddress;
    private DatagramSocket clientSocket;
    private TanksComponent tank;
    private byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    private int port = 9876;

    public UDPClient(TanksComponent tanksComponent) throws SocketException, UnknownHostException{
        this.tank = tanksComponent;
        this.clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        this.ipAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    }
    public void run(){

        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
        try {
            clientSocket.receive(packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        String message = new String(packet.getData());
        System.out.println("SERVER > " + message);
    }
    public void sendData(byte[] data){
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, ipAddress, port);
        try {
            clientSocket.send(packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am invoking the code like this :

```
 public void start() throws UnknownHostException, SocketException {
      if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Server") == 0){
            socketServer = new UDPServer();
            socketServer.start();

  }else{
      socketClient = new UDPClient(this);
      socketClient.start();
      System.out.println("Send");
      socketClient.sendData("ping".getBytes());
  }
```

Thanks for the help kind stranger !

Comment: Is there a reason you chose to use `DatagramSocket` instead of `Socket`?

Comment: To be honest I learnt that way, I am not sure the difference between them =/

Comment: Let me know if my answer below helps or if you have any questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a ton of experience with Java networking but feel free to look at a project I've been working on recently:

- [server](https://github.com/imapepper/checkersmis307/blob/master/src/sockets/GameHost.java)
- [client](https://github.com/imapepper/checkersmis307/blob/master/src/sockets/GameClient.java)